# Automatically add and remove class of an element based on active state of slider. Not on click, but automatic change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slider which is adding a class 'active' for current slide. I have another block with captions of this slider, but it is not inside the slider. So how can i add and remove class of the captions based on the 'active' state of slider. Slider is in autoplay. In detail, when it shows slide 1, then the caption should show 1, and so on. How can i achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slide active"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
</div>


<div class="captions">
<div class="caption1">One</div>
<div class="caption2">Two</div>
<div class="caption3">Three</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: anybody can help me because i'm not very good in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Look for the jQuery trigger function.

> http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

A solution could be.

```
$(".slide").trigger('cssClassChanged')
$(".captions > *").bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ do stuff });
```

Comment: I tried as follows but nothing happened.

`code`
$(".slide").trigger('cssClassChanged');
    $(".captions > *").bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('test');
    });
`code`

Comment: I don't have enough code to give you a specific answer. but the trigger function is what you will need.

Comment: Thank you i'll move on with 'trigger'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to do that.
What you need is simple setInterval() function. It takes two parametrs, function and interval time:

```
setInterval(function(){...}, 1000); //Every second your function will work
```

To make slider you need something like:

```
var target = $(".slider .slide" + i) //where i will be number
```

Make sure you change in .slider each slide className to slide1, slide2... to make this work.
Then you just need each interval time: i + 1; When i will reach your slider count (just test with: if(i > 2){i = 0}).

So in the end write in your interval function that:

```
target.addClass("active");
if( i < 2) {
i++;}else{
```

`i = 0;`}

Comment: maksims, thank you, i'm not very good in javascript but i'll look your code for future reference.